# ASP.NET Холодный старт и заказчики

Tags: asp.net, хостинг, заказчик

Часто заказчику требуется сайты, которые не подразумевают большую нагрузку. Поэтому заказчику обычно проще предложить виртуальный хостинг вместо VDP/VPS для размещения мною разработанного сайта на ASP.NET. Однако на виртуальном хостинге обычно нет возможности решить проблему холодного старта (лишь 1 раз мне удалось добиться от техподдержки, чтобы они поставили suspend и idle time out в ноль).

**Вопросы:**

1. Как поступаете вы (разработчики сайтов на asp.net) в таких ситуациях? Я мучаюсь с этим дело и не могу брать нормально заказы из-за этой проблемы.
2. Знаете ли вы простой виртуальный хостинг, где техподдержка позволяет корректировать такие параметры как idle time out?

Comment: Решилось все с помощью решения,которое предложили ниже [ссылка](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> на виртуальном хостинге обычно нет возможности решить проблему холодного старта

Как вариант можно периодически 'будить' сайт c помощью Cache и CacheItemRemovedCallback. Пример на C# есть в статье [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc) (у этого решения за 10 лет почти миллион просмотров, и почти максимальный рейтинг).
В ASP.NET 4 можно использовать [startMode](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series).

Comment: startMode без доступа к настройкам IIS не задать, а доступа-то у автора и нет. Кстати, от версии ASP.NET тут ничего не зависит.

Comment: Cache и CacheItemRemovedCallback не будет работать если IIS остановит процесс.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"не будет работать если IIS остановит процесс"_ -- мы же не знаем, остановит или нет. в такой ситуации, и если других вариантов нет, то почему бы не попробовать?!

Comment: у статьи с решением на основе Cache за 10 лет почти миллион просмотров, почти максимальный рейтинг, а тут ссылку на эту статью минусуют. что-то не так в консерватории :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"а доступа-то у автора и нет."_ -- не нет, а как сказал автор - "обычно нет", т.е. доступ бывает.

Comment: @Stack, при наличии доступа - тема теряет актуальность, актуальность при отстутствии) имея доступ ставишь suspend и забыл

Comment: @WimmDeveloper понятно, а решение на основе Cache пробовали использовать?

Comment: @Stack впервые о нем слышу, еще не попробовал. Вы пробовали его?

Answer (score 1):

Сократить время холодного старта можно

- прекомпиляцией видов (ищите подробности в доках по ASP.NET, готовьтесь также долго настраивать MSBuild),
- настройкой многоэтапной загрузки сайта (актуально в случае "тяжелых" обработчиков Application_Start).

Но холодный старт все равно будет занимать ощутимое время. Поэтому лучше всего - объяснить заказчику ситуацию, пусть сам выбирает: VDS или длинный холодный старт.

Еще 1 возможный вариант, на который некоторые заказчики могут согласиться - арендовать один VDS и хостить многим заказчикам сайты на нем (заодно станет понятно, почему техподдержка хостингов так не любит ставить suspend и idle time out в ноль)