# MVC все время работающий поток

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Я хочу сделать мини-онлайн-браузерную игру, используя ASP.NET MVC, и столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужно, чтобы был какой-то все время работающий поток, который с течением времени будет изменять некие параметры. Отправляя запрос  - браузер будет получать JSON о состоянии объектов в мире.

Но возможно ли вообще в MVC создать поток, работающий все время?

Comment: "некие параметры" - это что конкретно?

Comment: например есть число k. Пользователь отправляет POST запрос - я в этом потоке изменяю число k на k+1. Другой пользователь в другое время отправляет GET запрос - я возвращаю ему уже k+1, которое достаю из потока. Так вообще возможно чтобы поток не уничтожался с завершением запроса?

Comment: _"создать поток, работающий все время?"_ -- а для чего? получил параметры, вычислил что-то. сохранил. спит. пришел запрос. проснулся отдал результат. опять спит.

Comment: А если поток что-то делает с этим числом k? Например постоянно увеличивает его на единицу, или изменяет по какому-то закону... Что-то типа имитации жизни

Comment: _"чтобы поток не уничтожался"_ -- когда приложение проснулось, то потоки берутся из пула. если новых запросов не будет, то через какое-то время приложение заснет.

Comment: То есть постоянно работать приложение заставить нельзя? Плохо, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: _"имитации жизни"_ -- это можно реализовать если использовать cache. и он будет оживлять приложение по колбеку.

Comment: пример тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475465/asp-net-%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/475521#475521

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую сделать, как вы сказали

Comment: Решить такую задачу можно на SignalR.